# Searching in a List with Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq, filter

I am trying to search for objects that include a certain string in a field of the object(Title). Afterwards I would like to fill a list with the objects that include that string. My list is not getting filled up.

```
    public void SearchMovies(String searckhQuery) {
    Console.WriteLine(searckhQuery);
    if(searckhQuery == null) {
        Console.WriteLine("yesbaby");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("itworks");
        List<MovieViewModel> searchMovieList = new List<MovieViewModel>();
        movieList.Where(m => m.Title.Contains(searckhQuery));
        movieList.Select(m => searchMovieList);
        movieList = searchMovieList;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Its because you are not assigning the result of each call. `var searchMovieList  = movieList.Where(m => /*condition here*/).Select(m => new MovieViewModel{}).ToList();`

Comment: Also what does `searckhQuery` contain? Do you really want to do `Title.Contains(searchQuery)` ? That would return `true` if the title contains a partial complete match on the string searchQuery. Example: `"Dawn of the Dead"` title would match `"Dead"` but not `"Dead and Dawn"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how the linq queries work. The `Where` and `Select` return a new collection. It will not filter down the same list object. The syntax would be :

```
searchMovieList = movieList.Where(m => m.Title.Contains(searckhQuery)).ToList();
```

If the `MovieViewModel` and `movieList` is a collection of different types, then we will need to use `Select` and assign the properties as needed like:

```
searchMovieList = movieList.Where(m => m.Title.Contains(searckhQuery))
                          .Select(m => new MovieViewModel() 
                                       {
                                          Title = m.Title,
                                          .....
                                       }).ToList();
```

If both are of same type then it can be made more simple :

```
movieList = movieList.Where(m => m.Title.Contains(searckhQuery)).ToList();
```

Comment: @JonathanClaeskens glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

`Where` and `Select` are not methods that manipulate a `List<>`. They work on any `IEnumerable<>` and `List<>` is one of them, but they return a new sequence with the result. You never use that return value, so your list stays empty.

It's hard to tell what you actually want from a snippet that does not do it, but I think you were looking for this:

```
var searchMovieList = movieList.Where(m => m.Title.Contains(searckhQuery)).ToList();

if(!searchMovieList.Any())
{
    searchMovieList = movieList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do the following:
`var searchMovieList = movieList.Where(m => m.Title.Contains(searchQuery).toList()`